# Radar Control; is it possible for ATC to instruct track instead of heading?

Tags: radar, separation

Is it possible to use the track instead of headings in the aim to apply a radar separation?

Comment: [related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8000/what-are-the-differences-between-bearing-vs-course-vs-direction-vs-heading-vs-tr)

Answer (score 8):

Radar controllers take wind into consideration when issuing **headings** - "Fly heading one six zero".

Issuing a track would not be practical. This puts the burden of figuring out what course to fly on the pilot. Not all aircraft have a glass cockpit or instrumentation necessary to *easily, quickly, and accurately* compute a heading to fly to stay on course. The radar controller knows real-time information, knows the 'big picture', and has practice issuing headings.

Actual position is used to provide separation. Heading doesn't matter for separation.

Comment: "Issuing a track would not be practical." No, it wouldn't be impractical, it would be impossible. By definition, track is what the plane flew over ground. You cannot assign what to have done in the past.

Comment: @Andreas, in this case ‘track’ means _direction_ of track and that can be assigned. But it can only be flown by GPS and controllers can't assume aircraft have that.

Comment: Well, I certainly *understood* what was *meant*, but that doesn't mean it was *written* what was meant. We have to go by what was written and cannot interpret around at will. And "direction of track" would mean you extrapolate the track (from the past), and ATC doesn't assign that. "... and that can be assigned". No, it can not. If you disagree, show a source, or I won't continue this discussion. What was *meant* ... I think the op just misused the term, he/she meant *course*. ("Is it possible to use the course instead of headings ...") and just didn't know that what he/she thinks of is course

Answer (score 2):

No, ATC will not issue instructions to aircraft to maintain a specific track. From ICAO Document 4444 (PANS-ATM):

> 8.6.5.1    Vectoring shall be achieved by issuing to the pilot specific **headings** which will enable the aircraft to maintain the desired track.

If a controller wishes an aircraft to fly a specific track toward/away from a VOR navigational beacon, they may instruct pilots to fly a certain *VOR radial*, which is essentially a track. However, this only works if flying to or from a VOR or similar beacon.

Comment: I guess then that SIDs and STARs should be banned altogether since they do not comply with ICAO.

Comment: SIDs and STARs are not vectoring. The question is specifically about ATC issued instructions (radar vectoring), not about ATS routes (SIDs, STARs, airways, RNAV routes etc.)